# Falha ao Capturar Dispositivo USB J-Link com Virtual Box, MACOSX SAM4S XPlaned

Tags: virtualbox

A muitos anos uso meu MacBook juntamente com Virtual Box para programar em aplicativos que somente existem para Windows, porém atualmente estou precisando desenvolver um Firmware para um Cortex-M3 e para testes estou usando um SAM4S Xplaned da ATMel. Eu usava outro notebook para programar estes Hardware, e tudo funcionava bem também, mas agora estou unificando tudo no MAC puro ou no Windows com o VirtualBox, e estou tendo problema com o  Depurador J-Link que funciona perfeitamente no MAC OS através do Driver Segger J-Link, porém ao tentar sequestrar esta conexão USB para o VirtualBox (Versão 4.3.20) e estou recebendo a mensagem de erro abaixo da imagem.

[image: Imagem da mensagem de Erro]

Alguém já passou problema similar e sabe qual seria a solução? É um problema especifico do VirtualBox ou do SEGGER J-LINK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema se dá quando o Driver SEGGER para dispositivos J-Link captura a porta USB no MAC-OS, para evitar tal problema é necessário configurar um filtro de dispositivos USB nas configurações da Maquina Virtual em questão no VirtualBox.

Para isso, vá no menu "Máquinas" na janela relativa a sua maquina virtual, submenu "Configurações" e selecione a aba "Portas" e em seguida a sub-aba "USB".

Conecte normalmente o dispositivo em questão, e em seguida clique no botão que representa um conector **USB** com um símbolo **+** (mais/soma) sobreposto, é o segundo icone a direita, assim será listada as portas USBs configuradas que podem ser filtradas para a Maquina Virtual, assim selecione a porta "SEGGER J-Link" como na figura abaixo.

Então remova o dispositivo em questão, espere que a remoção seja reconhecida pelo SO Hospedeiro, e conecte novamente, agora o Virtual Box irá automaticamente capturar a porta USB para a maquina Virtual em questão.

[image: Filtragem de Portas USB]